# Как изменить содержимое метатега "Description"?

Tags: php, denwer

Всем привет!

Делал тут сайт и в "Description" просто написал "HELLO WORLD".

Сайт делал на Denwer'e,  PHP 5.6.8.

Сегодня закончил и выставил его на хостинг, а  метатег "Description" изменить забыл.

А теперь не получается его изменить.

Его содержимое я конечно изменил на нужное значение и сто раз сохранил.

Но при нажатии на кнопку "Поделится ссылкой на Фейсбуке или Одноклассниках", выскакивает его старое значение  "HELLO WORLD".

Где именно еще надо его менять вручную?

Кто-нибудь знает?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: может на сервере надо изменить?)

Comment: <meta property="og:description" content="ku" />

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 0):

В общем неправильный метатег "Description" никак не изменишь!

Т.к. эта информация сохраняется в стилях самого Фейсбука. Я думаю что при обращении к этому домену, достается эта сохраненная информация внутри самого Фесбука.

Хорошо что у меня сервер - мой, учебный. Поменял адрес домена - Фейсбук, Одноклассники и т.д. стали отображать уже новое содержание "Description"a!

Так что при работе с данным метатегом будьте осторожны - перед выкладыванием его на сервер клиента проверьте обязательно "Description"!

Спасибо всем за посильную помощь!